# task defined in parent gradle file does not run all commands

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I created this task from the parent build.gradle file.
It runs successfully but only creates 1 of the ear files, remoteLoad.ear
Looking at the output, it does not look like it is running the commands from the load project.
This is the task in the parent gradle file:
apply plugin: 'java'

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
task buildAll (dependsOn: 
    [ project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadCleanCompileStage,
      project(':load').loadCleanCompileStage,
      project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadPackage,
      project(':load').loadPackage
    ])
}
```

Why does it appear to be skipping the 'load' project tasks?

Comment: Try to run the task with `-i` CLI switch and see if the task was added to the graph and if skipped - why.

Comment: So the tasks for the Load project are not being configured.  The remoteLoad project is configured and it outputs the tasks that can be executed.  The load project states: **Task ':load:clean-compile' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.** The 2 tasks in the load project are just calls to the Ant build file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me...

```
apply plugin: 'java'

    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        task compileAll (dependsOn: [project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadCleanCompileStage]) {
             compileAll.finalizedBy project(':load').loadCleanCompileStage
        }

        task packageAll (dependsOn: [project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadPackage]) {
            packageAll.finalizedBy project(':load').loadPackage
        }

        task buildAll (dependsOn: [compileAll]) {
            buildAll.finalizedBy packageAll
        }
    }
```